# Golang Gin binding:"required,dive" not works

Tags: go, validation, go-gin

I have struct like below:

```
type TextMessage struct {
    Contacts []struct {
        Profile struct {
            Name string `json:"name"`
        } `json:"profile"`
        WaID string `json:"wa_id"`
    } `json:"contacts" binding:"required,dive"`
    Messages []struct {
        From      string `json:"from"`
        ID        string `json:"id"`
        Timestamp string `json:"timestamp"`
        Text      struct {
            Body string `json:"body"`
        } `json:"text"`
        Type string `json:"type"`
    } `json:"messages" binding:"required,dive"`
}
```

However incoming Message have no text json tag, but validation is passed and no any error I saw:

```
err = c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&textMessage, binding.JSON)
//answer: err is nil
```